# MySQL IF clause Issue

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT
   -> IF(status='EndSP',reportId,'') as 'reportId_EndSP'
   -> FROM T_Name LIMIT 10;
+--------------+
| reportId_EndSP |
+--------------+
|                |
|                |
| 270241         |
|                |
| 270242         |
|                |
|                |
| 270244         |
|                |
|                |
+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

But i need to return only the row where status = 'EndSP'
```

I don't need the else clause to be executed.

I can simply achieve that by writing

```
SELECT reportId FROM T_Name where status='EndSP';
```

but i need to do it using if or case.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

My actual query looks like

```
SELECT
   -> IF(status='EndSP',reportId,'') as 'reportId_EndSP',
   -> IF(status='EndSP',createdTS,'') as 'createdTS_EndSP',
   -> IF(status='BeginSP',reportId,'') as 'reportId_BeginSP',
   -> IF(status='BeginSP',createdTS,'') as 'createdTS_BeginSP'
   -> FROM T_Name HAVING reportId_EndSP!='' AND reportId_BeginSP!='' LIMIT  10;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
      IF(status='EndSP',reportId,'') as reportId_EndSP
      FROM T_Name) a
WHERE reportId_EndSP != '' LIMIT 10;
```

demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1167/8

or the single select version

```
SELECT
   IF(status='EndSP',reportId,'') as reportId_EndSP
   FROM T_Name
HAVING reportId_EndSP != '' LIMIT 10;
```

demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1167/9

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1.....Have a look at my edit/update part...I am getting 0 rows in resuLt set.

Comment: How about using `OR` instead of `AND` in having, it is physically impossible for `status` to be equal both `EndSP` and `BeginSP` at the same time for a single row!

Comment: Simplified fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1167/16 , removed the rows I didn't have and renamed BeginSP to StartSP - but it should prove the point

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *only* `IF`/`CASE` because they do not filter out the values from the result set, when the `IF` or `CASE` is called, the result set is already decided.

Comment: So is there any other way to do that withot using where clause..?

Comment: You can use a `HAVING` clause but it'd be peculiar. You could filter out the results in the programming language where they'll be received. Or you could use a select over the primary select and add a WHERE clause there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 reportId as 'reportId_EndSP'
 FROM T_Name where  IF(status='EndSP',reportId,' ') LIMIT 10;
```